# Love and caring (Frankfurt)

Tags: love

In his work, [Harry Frankfurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Frankfurt) uses 'caring' and 'loving' as two separate things. But what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Harry Frankfurt. These are a themes that occurs in multiple works, like 'the reasons of love' and 'taking ourselves seriously & getting it right'

Answer (score 2):

See : Harry Frankfurt, [The Reasons of Love](https://books.google.it/books?id=3hLnK2_erjYC&pg=PA11), Princeton University Press (2006), page 11:

> to say that there is something *we care about*, or — in a phrase that I shall employ (perhaps a bit willfully) as closely equivalent to this — something *we regard as important to ourselves*. In certain cases, moreover, what moves us is an
>   especially notable variant of caring: namely, *love*.

And page 16:

> Besides wanting to fulfill his desire, then, the person who cares about what he desires wants something else as well: he wants the desire to be sustained. Moreover, this desire for his desire to be sustained is not a merely ephemeral inclination. It is not transient or adventitious. It is a desire with which the person identifies himself, and which he accepts as expressing what he really wants.

Thus, *to care of* implies *reasons* and *projectuality*, more than simple *desire*.

And page 23:

> The totality of the various things that a person cares about — together with his ordering of how important to him they are — effectively specifies his answer to the question of how to live.

See page 29:

> The commands to which they do in fact respond [when people commits to the
>   well-being of their children] are grounded in a source that is constituted not by judgments and reasons, but by a particular mode of caring about things. They
>   are commands of love.

See page 31:

> So far I have characterized what I refer to as “love” only as a particular mode of caring.

And finally, page 37:

> Loving someone or something essentially means or consists in, among other things, taking its interests as reasons for acting to serve those interests. Love is itself, for the lover, a source of reasons. It creates the reasons by which his acts of loving concern and devotion are inspired.

Thus, *love* is by itself the reason for *care about* someone.